How to enforce specific implementation of an interface, depending on implementation of containing interface?
Supposing I have the following interfaces:
public interface IVehicle 
{
    ITrackInfo TrackInfo { get; set; }
    void ShowInfo();
}

public interface ITrackInfo
{
   int Length { get; set; }
}

Now I have these classes implementing ITrackInfo
public class RailInfo : ITrackInfo
{
   int Length { get; set;}
   int SleeperSpacing { get; set; }
}

public class CanalInfo : ITrackInfo 
{
   int Length  { get; set; }
   decimal AverageDepth { get; set; }
}

public class RoadInfo : ITrackInfo
{ 
   int Length { get; set; }
   Color Colour { get; set; }
}

But with the classes that implement IVehicle, I want them to have a specific implementation of ITrackInfo.
public class Train : IVehicle 
{
   RailInfo TrackInfo { get; set; }
   public void ShowInfo() {
      Console.WriteLine("Railway is {0}km long". TrackInfo.Length.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine("Distance between sleepers is {0}cm", TrackInfo.SleeperSpacing);
   }

}

public class Boat : IVehicle 
{
   CanalInfo TrackInfo { get; set; }
   public void ShowInfo() {
      Console.WriteLine("Canal is {0}km long". TrackInfo.Length.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine("The average depth is {0}m", TrackInfo.AverageDepth.ToString("F2"));
   }
}

public class Bus : IVehicle
{
   RoadInfo TrackInfo { get; set; }
   public void ShowInfo() {
      Console.WriteLine("Road is {0}km long". TrackInfo.Length.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine("The road is coloured {0}", TrackInfo.Colour.ToString());
   }
}

Obviously I can't write it as shown above - this produces a compile error in the IVehicle implementations as the TrackInfo property must be specified as ITrackInfo.
Is there a way of forcing specific implementations of ITrackInfo for specific implemenations of IVehicle?
I'm hoping for something a bit more elegant than just putting a check in ShowInfo():
var info = TrackInfo as RailInfo;
if (info == null)
{ 
    throw new Exception("Incorrect track info");
}


"this produces a compile error in the IVehicle implementations as the TrackInfo property must be specified as ITrackInfo." - that's what explicit implementation is for.

BTW, does the TrackInfo property really need to be mutable? If not, then if you make it get-only then you can take advantage of type-variance.

Train: IVehicle<CanalInfo> first what comes in mind. But do you really need to couple TrackInfo into vehicles? Why not use manager, which knows vehicles types and stuff?

What should happen if someone does IVehicle veh = new Boat() { TrackInfo = new CanalInfo() }; veh.TrackInfo = new RailInfo(); ? (Protip: interface types are fantastic for exposing a read-only view of an object, and it being read-only means its typing is correct under (variance)).

@Dai - that's what I'm trying to prevent!


Is there a way of forcing specific implementations of ITrackInfo for specific implemenations of IVehicle?

Yes, use generics like this:
public interface IVehicle<TI> where TI: ITrackInfo 
{
    TI TrackInfo { get; set; }
    void ShowInfo();
}

Here you are saying that TrackInfo's type will be a concrete implementation of ITrackInfo.
With this in your hand, the IVehicle implementations can be fixed:
public class Train: IVehicle<RailInfo>
{
   public RailInfo TrackInfo { get; set; }
   public void ShowInfo() 
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Railway is {0}km long", TrackInfo.Length.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine("Distance between sleepers is {0}cm", TrackInfo.SleeperSpacing);
   }
}

public class Boat: IVehicle<CanalInfo> 
{
   public CanalInfo TrackInfo { get; set; }
   public void ShowInfo() 
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Canal is {0}km long", TrackInfo.Length.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine("The average depth is {0}m", TrackInfo.AverageDepth.ToString("F2"));
   }
}

public class Bus: IVehicle<RoadInfo>
{
   public RoadInfo TrackInfo { get; set; }
   public void ShowInfo() 
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Road is {0}km long", TrackInfo.Length.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine("The road is coloured {0}", TrackInfo.Colour.ToString());
   }
}

Dotnet Fiddle link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GAb9k9

The straightforward solution is to just use explicit interface implementation, which allows a class with conflicting-named members to fully implement an interface.
public class Boat : IVehicle 
{
    public CanalInfo TrackInfo { get; set; } // <-- Keep-in-mind that this is an auto-property with a hidden backing-field.

    private ITrackInfo? ivTrack;

    ITrackInfo IVehicle.TrackInfo // This syntax denotes an explicit implementation, and is a manually-implemented property.
    {
        get => this.ivTrack;
        set => this.ivTrack = value;
    }

    public void ShowInfo()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Canal is {0}km long". this.TrackInfo.Length.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine("The average depth is {0}m", this.TrackInfo.AverageDepth.ToString("F2"));
   }
}

...but there's a few problems here:

Boat.TrackInfo and Boat.IVehicle.TrackInfo are entirely separate properties. Within Boat, using this.TrackInfo will always return the CanalInfo property, but any consumers of Boat that access it via the IVehicle interface will only have access to the ITrackInfo-typed property, which is distinct.

Because both the CanalInfo and ITrackInfo properties have set accessors, it means that (absent clarification documentation) that the Boat class has to accept any implementation of ITrackInfo to the ITrackInfo IVehicle.TrackInfo setter - and that would put the Boat object into a strange state then, because then its TrackInfo could return a RoadInfo.
i.e.
Boat titanic = new Boat()
{
    TrackInfo = new CanalInfo()
};

IVehicle veh = titanic;
veh.TrackInfo = new RoadInfo();

Debug.Assert( Object.ReferenceEquals( titanic, veh ) );
Debug.Assert( titanic.TrackInfo is CanalInfo );
Debug.Assert( veh.TrackInfo is RoadInfo );




One possible solution to the problem above is to make IVehicle a read-only interface, so IVehicle.TrackInfo is get-only, which means it can always safely just forward to Boat.TrackInfo, like so:
public interface IReadOnlyVehicle 
{
    ITrackInfo TrackInfo { get; }

    void ShowInfo();
}

public class Boat : IReadOnlyVehicle
{
    public CanalInfo TrackInfo { get; set; } // <-- Keep-in-mind that this is an auto-property with a hidden backing-field.

    ITrackInfo IReadOnlyVehicle.TrackInfo => this.TrackInfo; // Shorthand get-only property.

    public void ShowInfo()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Canal is {0}km long". this.TrackInfo.Length.ToString());
      Console.WriteLine("The average depth is {0}m", this.TrackInfo.AverageDepth.ToString("F2"));
   }
}

(As an aside, provided you're using C# 8 (or is it 9?) you can then take advantage of Covariant Return Types too)

There might be utility in making IReadOnlyVehicle a generic interface because then you can take advantage of other kinds of variance supported by .NET:
using IReadOnlyVehicle = IReadOnlyVehicle<ITrackInfo>; // <-- The non-generic identifier `IReadOnlyVehicle` is now just a type-alias of the closed-generic interface type.

public interface IReadOnlyVehicle<out TTrackInfo> // <-- Notice the `out` modifier here.
    where TTrackInfo : ITrackInfo
{
    TTrackInfo TrackInfo { get; }
}

public class Boat : IReadOnlyVehicle<CanalInfo>
{
    public CanalInfo TrackInfo { get; set; } // <-- Keep-in-mind that this is an auto-property with a hidden backing-field.

    public void ShowInfo() => yada;
}

// ...which then allows you to safely up-cast in full type-safety *and* by preserving reference-identity too.

Boat boat = new Boat() { TrackInfo = new CanalInfo() };

IReadOnlyVehicle<CanalInfo> vehicleInACanal = boat;

IReadOnlyVehicle vehicle = vehicleInACanal;

// Static types:
typeof(vehicle        .TrackInfo) == ITrackInfo
typeof(vehicleInACanal.TrackInfo) == CanalInfo
typeof(boat           .TrackInfo) == CanalInfo

Of course, only Boat has the property-setter.

Embrace Immutability
Once you design your types (class, interface, delegate, etc) as immutable data-structures, or at least, preferring to expose only read-only interfaces or views over them, then that (somewhat paradoxically) takes away many of the unergonomic problems inherent in OOP (excuse the pun) such as being able to correctly predict (or assert) the state of an object at any given point in your program or software system (e.g. supposing you have a fully-mutable Product object being passed around as a method parameter argument; it's going to be very difficult to be able to prove that the state of that Product object is in a valid state whenever it's consumed by your methods (e.g. if myProduct.ProductId is a valid number or still 0, or if some String Name { get; set; } property is set to null, an empty-string "", or something actually meaningful in your problem-domain.
And they're just more ameniable to being freely passed around to other consumers which might not be aware of your actual subtypes and only have access to supertypes; for example, a read-only IFace<out T>-type can always be safely converted to a supertype (e.g. IReadOnlyList<String> can be stored in a slot typed as IReadOnlyList<Object> and/or IEnumerable<Object>) - but the same cannot be said for a mutable List<String> which cannot be safely used as though it were a List<Object>.

Also, read this: https://boxbase.org/entries/2020/aug/3/case-against-oop/
